# Connecting azure dream spark subscription in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6

Tags: visual-studio, azure, dreamspark

I understand that this issue is on the back log of the VS team.  In the mean time is there a work around that I can use to publish a web site under my Dream Spark subscription?

Comment: This won't work for me either, though in Visual Studio Pro 2013. It says I don't have a subscription even though I have a DreamSpark subscription and app.

Comment: It seems they have not gotten around to this issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has posted a work around for this for VS2013.  I assume it will work for the current previews of VS2015????  Have not had a chance to try it yet.  This page has a link for the instructions.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_student_developer_blog/archive/2015/04/09/using-microsoft-azure-for-students.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but if anyone, like me, searches for this problem, here's a solution: Go to Extensions and Updates and update the Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8.

[Visual Studio not finding my Azure subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507589/visual-studio-not-finding-my-azure-subscriptions/33923419#33923419)