# MS Azure and publish from VS without subscription credentials?

Tags: azure

In our organization, we have an Enterprise Azure Subscription and a few members of our team can use it with their own AD credentials.

For instance, I have the 'owner' role for my account, but don't have the login/pwd of the subscription.

However, in Visual Studio 2015, for a Azure Service, publish Azure application, I need to specify a account an choose the subscription.
And there is no subscription listed for my account.

[image: screenshot]

So what should I do to be able to publish from Visual Studio?
Or what further rights should I ask aside my 'owner' role in Azure?

EDIT: I opened the same topic on MSDN (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e242ae0a-8da3-49fd-9fff-0460c4e294b8/how-to-use-azure-publish-from-visual-studio-with-entreprise-team-subscription?forum=azureapimgmt)

EDIT: this topic has some interessting info but not directly related since I do NOT have the subscription myself:
[Visual Studio not finding my Azure subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507589/visual-studio-not-finding-my-azure-subscriptions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're working with multiple accounts...

You may not be signed into visual studio with the correct account. The `account name dropdown` in the upper right hand corner of visual studio and select `Account Settings`. From here ensure the account associated with your Azure resources is present under `All Accounts`. MS has some more guidance here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872465.aspx

Comment: thanks for your input, but as said, I do NOT have the subscription account!
So the question is: what further rights should I ask to my management to be able to publish from VS with my 'owner' role?

Comment: By "account" I mean whatever you use to log in to the portal. It doesn't have to be admin account. I am able to push to multiple subscriptions. Some I have admin, some I only have owner. There doesn't seem to be a difference from a VS perspective.

Comment: Read your edits. Maybe I'm not clear on your situation. Do you have an account that you log into the portal with or not? If you do, then you log in to your MS account and associated subscriptions should be enumerated. You don't need anything else. In my case I have multiple MS accounts and I have to make sure I'm logged in with the correct one or things get a little weird, like saying I have no subscriptions.

Comment: Yes, I do have a portal account where i log to Azure.Portal. This account has Owner role and I am able to create/edit/update/delete ressources on the portal. This portal account has dual factor auth.
Then, I have my normal 'dev' account which i am using in my VM, and in Visual Studio. 
Visual Studio lists both account but is not able to retrieve anything on the Azure portal, although it is connected with the portal account

Comment: I suppose I need to ask the subscription manager and ask what I am supposed to do and what not.
For instance, on Azure portal, I cannot create support ticket, nor open the bash shell.

Comment: That should be enough. Same experience here when I'm not admin. Certain actions like opening support requests or scaling ASA jobs are not allowed, but I can still enumerate/connect/deploy/debug/etc from visual studio. MFA shouldn't be an issue, I've been in that scenario too. The failure to enumerate still very strongly leads me to believe your account(s) need to be logged off and back on via the menu mentioned. Have you tried that yet?