# Visual Studio - Publish Web App to Azure "Reenter your credentials" does not work

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I can't publish an asp.net app to Azure Web App in Visual Studio 2015. It asks me to reenter my credentials, which I do, and then get the same "renter your credentials" screen.

I have two Azure accounts, one is my synced Azure AD identity (account@company.com), and the other as a cloud-only identity (account@company.onmicrosoft.com). When trying to log in with either of these accounts, Visual Studio still says "Reenter your credentials" and does not show any subscriptions or resource groups.

Looking at a Fiddler, I can see Azure return a list of all of my subscriptions, yet Visual Studio does not populate and thinks my credentials are invalid (Fiddler screenshot below)

[image: Issue Picture]

[image]

Comment: Thought I had it - I can see VS reading the accounts from this reg location:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\Keychain\Accounts

I deleted both my accounts from here, restarted visual studio. I was able to login with my account this time, but still get the "Reenter your credential" message.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507589/visual-studio-not-finding-my-azure-subscriptions][1]

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017 installed alongside and this works in 2017.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem

In the Acount settings of your visual studio top right..
Delete all acounts an then sign in with the proper azure account.

Then when you go to publish you can add the account

Comment: I suggest this be marked as the accepted answer. Just ran into this problem and logging into the account I was trying to add solved the problem immediatly. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced exactly what you describe here, however when I ensured that I was connected to Visual Studio using the same account as I wished to publish with, the "reenter credentials" message disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Options > Accounts**,

On the **"Add and reauthenticate accounts using:"** field select **Device code** .

Login in the browser with the provided code and then you are able to publish without re-entering credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with visual studio 2019,  my Microsoft account was linked with my gitHub account. I unlinked my github account by logging into my windows account going into security and unlinking the account

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with VS 2019 and 2022 (preview), but the account settings in Visual Studio only showed my 'Home Organization'. Deleting and re-adding didn't help.

Finally, I fixed it by removing an external organization that I was a member of from my account.

Go to https://myaccount.microsoft.com and login. On the left panel, select *Organizations* and delete all, except your Home Organization.

Of course, if you actually *need* the external organization(s), this isn't going to help you.