# Re-enter Your Credentils - can't connect to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-authentication

I try to login to Visual Studio using my work account. I have a VS Professional subscription.

After signing in, I have a message "Re-enter your credentials". When I try to re-enter my credentials, it redirects me to my account login, and I should confirm it with my Microsoft Authenticator app. I can't do this, my phone doesn't get a request and codes I try to enter are not correct.

So, basically, I am stuck with this issue and I can't publish anything to Azure.
I don't understand why does this issue happen.
I tried to disable Authenticator, but still the message to confirm identity via Authenticator shows up.

I tried to reset multifactor auth, tried restarting Visual Studio, removing account, signing out and signing in, tried to re-setup my Authneticator app - nothing works.

Anyone with the same issue or some solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you log into the Azure portal in your browser?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, I can. But I can't do it through VS.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue with Visual studio-2019 as shown below :

[image]

- To resolve the above issue Go to **File> Account Settings> Account Options> Accounts>** From the Drop down select **System web browser** instead of embedded web browser

[image]

- After above step done do a sign out and sign in again in **VS STUDIO**

After successfully configured able to deploy apps to **Azure** :

[image]

- Please refer this for more information [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471240/visual-studio-publish-web-app-to-azure-reenter-your-credentials-does-not-wor?rq=1)

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it still doesn't work for some reason.
P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2022

Comment: This was solved my issue . Could you please try Go to https://myaccount.microsoft.com and login. On the left panel, select your Organizations and delete all organizations except your Home Organization. Also refer the mentioned SO Thread in answer

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT  Thanks!  I had no idea we finally have self-service for that.

Answer (score 1):

- For publishing: you can always publish by download publish profile
  from azure websites or through CI/CD (Azure Devops)
- authentication error: you can might into issues if you have even
  signed in using personal email in visual studio so you might need to
  refer to this:
  [Clear stored TFS credentials in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017)
  for 2fa you can always use sms or phone call