# Visual Studio 2022 caches old tenant id, can't get rid of it

Tags: azure, visual-studio

Visual Studio picks the wrong tenant id in an attempt to login Azure in the integrated Microsoft Identity platform tool, I do not have such a GUID that it shows me, my tenant id Guid is different for the user, and user name is shown right in the error message. I tried to search the GUID that it shows me (starting at f8cd..) in Azure portal, but was not able to find anything, no idea where VS takes it from, could be some old one that I used long in the past.

[image]

I restarted studio, rebooted Windows, signed out, signed in, nothing helps. I clean up `\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth`, it did not help either.

When I type `az account show` in the cmd, it displays right user and right tenant id with home tenant id

Checking/unchecking the box in VS settings does not help either
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Need to check below steps:***

1. ***Cache issue:***

Goto the `account settings` on the top right corner of the Visual studio and remove all the existed logged in accounts and reenter your credentials with the required one. This will help you to resolve the cache issue.

[image]

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868707/visual-studio-not-showing-subscription-from-other-account-just-happened-last-w/75874296#75874296) worked by me for more relevant information.

2. Goto the

```bash
control panel >> User accounts >> Credential Manager >> Windows Credentials
```

*Remove the Visual Studio credentials as shown in the image and add it.*

[image]

3. Reset all settings in Visual Studio by going to
   `Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings`.

***Or***

```bash
Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Accounts >> Clear all the logged in accounts.
```

[image]

4. If none of the above works, try repairing the Visual Studio installation by going to

```bash
Control Panel >> Programs and Features >> Microsoft Visual Studio >> Change >> Repair
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists, uninstall the visual studio and reinstall it with the latest version from Visual studio official site.***

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing the same issues. Turns out we had a system environment variable set that was overriding the Azure account logged in within VS:

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-...."
```

After removing this environment variable, and restarting Visual Studio, the problem was resolved.