# Why I cannot deploy ASP.NET application to Azure?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET web application (React variant) to Azure. I need to log in to do this. The password, mail and Azure account all match and everything is fine, but it won't let me in. I don't even get any popups about a possible error. Is this a bug or some error on my part?

[image: What I am seeing after login]

Comment: Clear cache in Visual studio and try to signin again

Comment: If you mean to remove all accounts, then yes I have tried but it did not resolve my problem

Comment: Try to reset all settings in Visual Studio and check `Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings`.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I have tried it now... Same result...

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to repair or uninstall and reinstall visual studio.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I've just now made a correction, but still no fix....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen few cases regarding the same issue, it seems to be temporary issue due to Cache Problem or if there are any IDE Updates to be done which will automatically get fixed.

If you are still facing this issue, you can try below steps to fix the issue:

1. Clear Visual Studio cache and delete the previous credentials and also delete all the accounts if you have multiple. Restart visual studio once done with those steps and then re-login credentials.

`Your profile->Account Settings-> remove all the existed logged in accounts and reenter your credentials.`

[image]

2. To delete cache, go to  `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`  and clear all the cache.

[image]

- As mentioned in this [doc](https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/08/visual-studio-re-enter-credentials/),
  you can also try with `system web browser` instead of   `Embedded web broswer`.

[image]

If nothing works, try to **repair** the visual studio or **uninstall** and **reinstall** the visual studio.

**References:**

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953145/visual-studio-2022-caches-old-tenant-id-cant-get-rid-of-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Finally...The problem was with System web browser. Thank you sir, you haved saved my day