Azure Keyvault ForbiddenByRbac
I have difficulties connecting locally with my Azure Keyvault using the following code:
string tid = builder.Configuration["AzureADTenantId"];
    
DefaultAzureCredentialOptions o = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{
VisualStudioTenantId = tid,
SharedTokenCacheTenantId = tid 
};
        
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri($"https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential(o));

It results in the error:
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\n
If role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\n
Caller: appid=<APP_ID>;oid=<OID>;iss=https://sts.windows.net/<DIRECTORY_ID>/\r\n
Action: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/readMetadata/action'\r\n
Resource: '/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourcegroups/my-rg-process-service/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/mykv'\r\n
Assignment: (not found)\r\nDenyAssignmentId: null\r\nDecisionReason: null 
\r\nVault: mykv;location=westeurope\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}

I suspect it's is rather related to something locally on my system, as it used to work up until last week.
I tried using VisualStudioCredential. Same error unfortunately. I also checked my permissions:

And double checked my network config:

In powershell these commands work:
az login
az keyvault list
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "mykv" -Name "mysecret"

In Visual Studio itself, under Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication, my account should be set to the right account. It is part of multiple tenants though, however, my keyvault is part of the default tenant.
I don't know on what else to try anymore.

Could you check these ID values from error message Caller: appid=<APP_ID>;oid=<OID> and confirm whether those are related to app registration or user?

I cannot find any app registration that is related to <APP_ID>, tried checking that. I suspected that is something Microsoft does in the background? I did use to have another visual studio account setup as primary profile, but I switched it (at least, that is what the UI is telling me).

Have you tried checking app id in Enterprise applications tab by filtering All applications?

It's seems to be related to some cache or something. With DefaultAzureCredentialOptions you can exclude authentication methods. It looks like if I only keep ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential (for logic app) and ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential enabled, it get prompted at least in the browser to select an account. That works. Any idea how I can modify Visual Studio that it selects the right account without having to use the interactive browser?

The error occurs if there is any cache related issue or signed-in user not having access to Azure Key Vault.
Initially, I too got same error when the signed-in user does not have proper access or role on Azure Key Vault:

You can find the user account by copying oid value from error message and search it in Users tab as below:

In my case, I assigned "Key Vault Administrator" role to above user account under Azure Key Vault like this:

When I ran the code again after assigning role to user, error resolved and I'm able to connect Azure Key Vault successfully:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string tenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureADTenantId"];

DefaultAzureCredentialOptions credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
    VisualStudioTenantId = tenantId,
    SharedTokenCacheTenantId = tenantId
};

var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri($"https://kvname.vault.azure.net/");
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions));

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri($"https://kvname.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions));
        KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("secretname");
        return secret.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
});

app.Run();

Response:

Additionally, check if you are signed in with right user account or not and remove other accounts if any:

UPDATE:
If still the error persists, switch to interactive flow that prompts the user to pick the account for signing in.

Hi Sridevi, I can confirm it is 100% related to some caching issue on my local PC. Account is set to the right profile though. Do you know of any way to prune the Visual Studio cache or something?

Hi @usselite Have you tried signing out of existing accounts and sign in again with correct account. In Visual Studio, go to File > Account Settings > Sign out.
Sign back in with the correct Azure account. This clears the token cache and forces Visual Studio to reauthenticate.

To verify that Visual Studio is using the correct account: In Tools > Options, navigate to Azure Service Authentication. Ensure that the correct account is selected under Account Selection. Kindly edit your question and add those images confirming you are using single account in all areas.

Refer this SO thread to resolve cache issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953145/visual-studio-2022-caches-old-tenant-id-cant-get-rid-of-it#:~:text=Goto%20the%20control%20panel%20%3E%3E%20User%20accounts%20%3E%3E,Accounts%20%3E%3E%20Clear%20all%20the%20logged%20in%20accounts.

@usselite Any update on the issue?

thanks for reminding me. So I do have a work-around in place, not ideal (enforce browser choosing dialog). I followed the linked stackoverflow post: 1 - removed all accounts added primary, issue still exists. 2 - removed git authorization for azure devops, issue still exists. (meanwhile restarted VS). 3 - Reset all settings, however besides an unexpected error in the general section, issue still exists. 4. Over the last few days I did a rollback, as latest VS has a breaking bug involving ordering of unit tests by name. Guess that should work also as repair? Doesn't fix it though.

@usselite If still the issue persists, the only way for now is to make use of interactive flow that prompts the user to pick the account for signing in.

Yep, the interactive promp is my work-around right now.
