# Azure Identity and Resource Manager not finding subscriptions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-resource-manager, azure-identity, asp.net-core-7.0

Just getting started with Resource Manager in Visual Studio, but I cannot clear the first hurdle.

When I use the following code, client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync() returns the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No subscriptions found for the given credentials'

I am using my Azure/Microsoft account to log into Visual Studio, and it the same account selected under Azure Service Authentication in VS.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Network;

ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

SubscriptionResource subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
```

Seems like an incredibly basic first step but nothing I have found online has helped. What have I missed?

Comment: is your account associated to multiple tenant ?Can you try specifying the tenantId when instantiating the `DefaultAzureCredential` class?

Comment: I think it is only assigned to one: https://i.imgur.com/ujSjpEF.png
I also tried adding this, but had the same results.
var DACO = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() { TenantId = "****************************" };
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential(DACO));

Comment: when you receive the error, would you be able to check what is the access token receive ? Which tenant is it connected with ?

Comment: I wrote the following code, but it gave me the id of the tenant shown above:
DefaultAzureCredential defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

string resource = "https://management.azure.com/";
AccessToken accessToken = await defaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { resource + ".default" }));

JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken.Token);
string tenantId = jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "tid")?.Value;

Comment: so does the tenantid sounds right for you ?

Comment: Yes, it matches the account I am signed into VS with. It has a PAYG Subscription, in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Need to check below:***

- The issue here is that you might be using personal user as a general Microsoft account, which is "external" to the tenant.
- To make it work, create a new user in the default Azure AD directory and give necessary admin role permissions to the respective user.

  ***Steps clearly detailed in this*** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75874296/19785512) worked by me.

Once you are done with all the above steps, then try logging in with the newly created user credentials and it will work as expected.

- If still the issue persists, try logging out from Visual Studio and relog in/re-authenticate with Azure. It clears cache sometimes.

  Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75963839/19785512) worked by me for more Visual Studio "No subscription found" issues.

*Or else*

Goto `Tools >> Options >> Account selection in Azure Service Authentication` and remove all the existing accounts. Now login with the desired account credentials as shown.

[image]

Comment: Great response thank you. I have this working now. I thought I had tried these steps, but I think clearing the VS accounts, restarting VS, then logging into VS with the new AD account in that order is what I did not do.